# Not able to update objectClass attribute of AD domain group using ansible

Tags: powershell, ansible, active-directory

[Image where I modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipTSe.png)

Using Ansible trying to create AD domain group and update objectClass attribute.

```
- name: Create group
  community.windows.win_domain_group:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    scope: global
    category: security
    state: present
    attributes: "{{ item.attributes }}"
  with_items:
    - name: group1
      attributes:
        gidNumber: 1234
        objectClass:
          - group
          - posixGroup
          - top
```

Comment: Getting below error

failed: [ad1] (item={'name': 'group1', 'attributes': {'gidNumber': 1234, 'objectClass': ['group', 'posixGroup', 'top']}}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "created": false, "item": {"attributes": {"gidNumber": 1234, "objectClass": ["group", "posixGroup", "top"]}, "name": "group1"}, "msg": "failed to create group group1: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type 'System.String'."}

Similar thing is working for **domain user** but **not working** for **domain group**

Comment: You [cannot change the `objectClass` attribute of an object once created](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/object-class-and-object-category) in AD.

Comment: Active Directory Users and Computers -  Where we create users and groups, from this tool I am able to change attribute objectclass for both user and group. Using ansible for user I am able to change but not for group.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) for your suggestion. Posting this an answer to help other community member.

The objectClass property of a user object would identify the `top`, `person`, `organizationalPerson`, and `user` classes.

The system sets the `objectClass` value when the object instance is created and it cannot be changed.

Getting an error when I am trying to update the Object Class

[image]

Please refer this MS Article : [Object Class and Object Category - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/object-class-and-object-category)

Comment: I am able to edit objectClass attribute using Active Directory Users and Computers tool.